# Как встроить\вшить БД в программу на Win?

Tags: c++, база-данных, sqlite, c++builder

Использую C++ Builder и SQLite. Как поставлять БД вместе с программой? Пробовал в Deployment выставить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Link with runtime - false

Link with Dynamic RTL - false

На Android БД поставляется как локальная, как мне поставлять ее и на Win?

Может Remote Path нужно указать какой?

Answer (score 2):

Это делается типо этого

```
  FDConnection1->Params->Values['Database'] = IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter
    (System::Ioutils::TPath::GetDocumentsPath()) + 'tests.db';
```

прочитайте [**статью**](http://habrahabr.ru/company/delphi/blog/252345/) про создании приложения одновременно под Windows и Android. также из **[официального сайта](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_FireDAC_and_SQLite_(iOS_and_Android))**

Из сайта [http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath)

```
Платформа       Пример пути                      ID пути
Windows XP     C:\Documents and Settings\\My Documents     
                                                 CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS
                                                 CSIDL_PERSONAL
Windows Vista  C:\Users\\Documents               FOLDERID_Documents
или поже 
Mac OS X       /Users//Documents                 NSDocumentDirectory
iOS Device     /var/mobile/Applications//Documents
iOS Simulator  /Users//Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator//Applications//Documents
Android        /data/data//files                 Context.getFilesDir
```

Answer (score 1):

> как мне поставлять ее и на Win?

Вы пытаетесь работать с Windows и Android под одну гребёнку. А, решение, которое хорошо подходит для одной платформы не всегда также подходит для другой.

Для Windows нет необходимости включать БД в состав проекта. Её можно спокойно положить в папку, где, например, находится сама программа, прописав в программе соответствующий путь.

Потом, перед публикацией релиза, все нужные файлы соберёте в общий архив или инсталяционный пакет.

Comment: Нужно ли устанавливать дополнительные драйвера SQLite  или FireDac для взаимодействия с БД?

Comment: FireDAC имеет встроенный драйвер для SQLite.